# Marquee on TextView, blinking textview and Seekbar progress thread block the UI

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, ui-thread, android-runonuithread

I have three animation working on my App.

**1. TextView Marque (Scrolling continues)**

**2. Blinking Textview (When my Music app in pause mode)**

**3. SeekBar Progress thread (Shows the Progress of played song)**

While i use above all effect for my app, then UI for my my app becomes little hang. I guess all are working on the UI thread. I want to handle it as like each work independently without blocking each other.

**Code is like below:**

XML layout for the app:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/songCurrentDurationLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="00:00"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/songTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdgeLength="10dip"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"/>




    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/songProgressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="50"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/scrubber_progress_horizontal_holo_light"
        android:thumb="@drawable/scrubber_control_selector_holo"
        android:indeterminate="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

*My Class code is like below:*

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Animation blinking_anim;
    private SeekBar songProgressBar;
    private TextView songCurrentDurationLabel;
    private int count = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        blinking_anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.blinking_animation);
        songProgressBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.songProgressBar);
        songCurrentDurationLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.songCurrentDurationLabel);
        songCurrentDurationLabel.startAnimation(blinking_anim);
        mHandler.post(mUpdateTimeTask);
        songProgressBar.setMax(10000);
    }
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                count = count +10;
                songCurrentDurationLabel.setText(""+ count);
                songProgressBar.setProgress((int)count);
                System.out.println("Runnnnn.........MAIN....");
                if(count>=10000){
                    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
                }else
                    mHandler.post(mUpdateTimeTask);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

*Blinking Animation:*

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="1000" android:repeatCount="infinite">
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="4.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" android:duration="1000" android:repeatCount="infinite">
    </alpha></alpha>
</set>
```

Need help for implementing all this to work independently without hanging each other.

Comment: Take out thread.sleep and use handler.postdelayed with 100ms.

Comment: @ElDuderino you are right, with that UI thread become relaxed. but my requirement is to have progressbar very smooth that's why i can not give it Thread.Sleep(some seconds) or postDelayed for some seconds. Is there any other sollution? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: The smoothness depends on your update frequency, so just use postdelayed with less than 100ms.

Comment: @ElDuderino hummmm. Ok. Is there any other way that we can run each on independent thread?